# How to consume REST Endpoint with wso2 api manager?

Tags: json, rest, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I can consume SOAP APIs in my company with wso2 api manager. However when I want to consume REST endpoints I am unable to do so. I keep getting no response.

My endpoints are like such:

1. GET: http://{server}:{port}/api/broker/{brokerId}
2. POST: http://{server}:{port}/api/addresscleanse with json payload.

I am not seeing any configuration for the backend point where we can specify that the backend service is expecting json payload or queryparameter. I tried to scan the tutorial section and did not find any thing similar to my need.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your resources like below. To specify the message body type of the POST request, you can send `Content-Type` header.

[image]